# How to setup postgis extension for knex?

Tags: node.js, postgis, knex.js

I am new to node and are building a simple API to handle geographic data.
For this I am trying to implement [knex-postgis](https://github.com/jfgodoy/knex-postgis)

I have a connection file that I require in my queries.js like so:

```
const knex = require('./knex');
```

and use it

```
update(id, poi) {
    return knex('poi').where('id', id).update(poi, '*');
```

The doc say to implement the extension like this:

```
const knex = require('knex');
const knexPostgis = require('knex-postgis');

const db = knex({
  dialect: 'postgres'
});

// install postgis functions in knex.postgis;
const st = knexPostgis(db);
/* or:
 * knexPostgis(db);
 * const st = db.postgis;
 */
```

Can someone please explain where in my structure I implement the code, this is the first time I am using an extension. Do i put it in my knex.js file?

My knex.js look like this:

```
const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require('../knexfile');
const environmentConfig = config[environment];
const knex = require('knex');
const connection = knex(environmentConfig);
module.exports = connection;
```

EDIT:
I tried putting this in my queries.js file

```
const knex = require('./knex');
const knexPostgis = require('knex-postgis');
const st = knexPostgis(knex);
const db = knex({
  dialect: 'postgres'
});
```

My create function:

```
  create() {
    const sql = knex.insert({
      geom: st.geomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326)
    }).into('poi').toString();
    console.log(sql);
    return sql
```

It `console.log` a valid sql that works in pgadmin but in postman I get
`"message": "queries.create(...).then is not a function"`,

And finally my route

```
router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
    queries.create(req.body).then(poi => {
      res.json(poi[0]);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning string from your `create` method, but expect a promise interface in your route handler.
And you are using `knex` instead of `db` for query building.
Try this

```
const builder = db.insert(/*same as above*/).into('tablename');
const sql = builder.toString();
console.log(sql);
// Return builder instance itself (promise) instead of string
return builder;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so much to learn =) Green on using promise. I will try this out as soon as I can code again (setting up a new computer for my coding). Really appreciate it

Comment: I finally got it to work, with a small tweak to your suggestion. (adding .into('table'). To the builder. I.e const sql = db.insert({
      geom: st.geomFromText('Point(-71.064544 44.28787)', 4326)
    }).into('poi');
    console.log(sql.toString());
    return sql

Comment: When you say that the route handler is expecting a promise interface, do you mean that the route is expecting an object and not just the string. Have i understood that right?

Comment: @geogrow yea, in controller you call `create(...)` followed by `.then()`. Basically promise is an object with 2 methods then and catch. String doesn't have such methods.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `knex.insert`. You should be calling `db.insert`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that did not work. I added my route for more details, if that would shed some my light.
Do you know what const db = knex({
  dialect: 'postgres'
}); does?
Have we not set the dialect before in the connection to knex?

Comment: Adds hooks to generate code more optimized, schema-aware, and contextual with PostgreSQL: https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/tree/9122cbf6dfde7f347a4512ba63d32265becf7bb2/src/dialects/postgres

Comment: Your code absolutely won't work, so regardless of whether mine does what you want, you want to do what mine does.  you absolutely need to initialize the library. http://knexjs.org/#Installation-client

Comment: Hmm I feel really silly now, you were right. What I should not have done is to add. toString method at the end of building the insert query. I was quite literally following the example in the doc where it was used to print the query that was generated,. Thought it was required to make the insert to db.